# PHP How to get date of Monday and Sunday of the week in which the given date falls?

Tags: php, date

How can i get a `Date of Monday` and `Date of Sunday` if i have specific Date in `mysql` `DATETIME` format ?

i am trying to get the week's first day's date and last day's date in which the given date falls.

i have date '2016-06-05' its in `'Y-m-d'`
and i am trying it like this way.

```
<?php
$date = '2016-06-05'; 
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($date))), "\n";   
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week', strtotime($date))), "\n";
?>
```

but its giving

```
2016-06-06
2016-06-12
```

which is wrong week, it should give

```
2016-05-30
2016-06-05
```

i even tried like this way.

```
$date = '2016-06-05';
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday', strtotime('this week', strtotime($date)))), "\n";   
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday', strtotime('this week', strtotime($date)))), "\n";
```

OR

```
$date = '2016-06-05'; 
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday', strtotime($date))), "\n";   
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday', strtotime($date))), "\n";
```

using `PHP 5.3`

what am i missing here ?

---

UPDATE:

i came up with this, this is giving expected output.

```
function get_monday_sunday($date){
$dates_array = array();

    if(date('N', strtotime($date)) == 7){

    $dates_array['monday'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Monday last week', strtotime($date)));   
    $dates_array['sunday'] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Sunday last week', strtotime($date)));   

    }else{

    $dates_array['monday'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Monday this week', strtotime($date)));   
    $dates_array['sunday'] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Sunday this week', strtotime($date)));   
    }
return $dates_array;
}

$date = '2016-06-05'
print_r(get_monday_sunday($date));
```

looks like when  the day is last day of week, then next week starts over, i.e. php week start is sunday i guess.

Comment: echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week', strtotime($date))), "\n"; because sunday is the last day of the week in php

Comment: thanks, i have lots of dates, so will it work for any given date ?

Comment: I an not sure that sunday is the 1st or the last day is not set by server config. But in your current enviroment it will work

Comment: how about if i get a week number from date, then calculate the monday's date and sunday's date, using that week number ?

Comment: Get the monday  and then the sunday relative to it

Answer (score 3):

In every single php project I make, I always include the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted) package. It extends the DateTime class and adds some very nice functionality that makes working with dates a lot easier.

If you would take my suggestion, your code would look something like this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($dateStringFromDb);
echo $date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'); // monday
echo $date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');  // sunday
```

And that is really all there is to it. This is what I call "self commenting code"! I bet you're actually going to enjoy program with dates ;-)

Comment: thanks, ill look into it, for now i have came up with ugly solution.,